# jsonschema validation: value for a specific field should be limited to the values entered in another field

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv, react-jsonschema-forms

I was wondering if jsonschema can validate the value for a specific field that is limited to the values entered in another field. For example:

```
{
 "type": "object",
 "properties": {
  "someStrings": {
   "type": "array",
   "title": "some strings",
   "items": {
    "type": "string"
   }
  },
  "chooseOneOfSomeStrings": {
   "type": "string",
   "limitedTo": "someStrings" // or whatever the verbiage to implement this
  }
 }
}
```

Thus

If I entered "red", "blue", "green" for "someStrings", "chooseOneOfSomeStrings" would be valid if it was "red" and invalid if it was "yellow".

Answer (score 1):

The keyword you are looking for is "enum". But this list of allowed values needs to be in the schema itself -- it can't be in the data that you are validating.

```
...
  "chooseOneOfSomeStrings": {
   "type": "string",
   "enum": [ "red", "blue", "green" ]
  }
```

Comment: I can't use the `enum` since it depends on the dynamic choices made on `someStrings`. Looks like I need to make a custom validator.